# Posting with httparty records and children records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

A bit of difficulty handling multiple children associations for posting to another rails application via Httparty gem.

From the sending application:

```
:parent has_many :kids
:kid    has_many :schools

@parent = Parent(parent_params)
@parent = HTTParty.post("http://localhost:3001/parents/import", 
:body => { :parent_id => @parent.id, 
           :terms_accepted => @parent.terms_accepted, 
           :email => @parent.email, 
           :kids => {
             @parent.kid.school.name => @parent.kid.school_name,
             @parent.kid.age => @parent.kid.age
           }
         }.to_json,
:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```

The receiving application has the same relationship

```
:parent has_many :kids
```

the combination of array of `kids` and the use of singular and plural in the post syntax is throwing me off...

The console is showing:

```
"kids_attributes" => {"0"=>{"age"=>"10", "school_id"=>"8"}, "1"=>{"age"=>"11", "school_id"=>"9"},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent has_many Kids, then its expected to have an array here, try the following:

```
:kids => @parent.kids.map {|kid| {:school_name => kid.school.name, :age => kid.school.age }}
```

Comment: Something quirky with brackets and parenthesis `syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ')'`

Comment: should be fixed